# message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE, State: URL_UNREACHABLE, Reason: UNREACHABLE_5xx, HTTP status code: 500." in dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

I am trying to send email using dialogflow intents from my gmail.  But it throws the same error every time and I am unable to understand the issue behind this.  The same thing stand alone from my code is able to send emaail to various email addresses. So i guess the code works just fine . Please have  a look at my code .

```
'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const axios = require("axios");
admin.initializeApp({
 credential:admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
databaseUrl:'ws://***************/'
});
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }
 
  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
function emailSend(){
    const email= agent.parameters.email;
    const name= agent.parameters.name;
    const subject= agent.parameters.subject;
    const message = agent.parameters.message;

}





const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: '*****@gmail.com',
    pass: '***********'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'Mamuni',
  to: 'email' ,
  subject: 'subject' ,
  text: 'message' 
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});

let intentMap = new Map();  
intentMap.set('emailSend',emailSend);
 
intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error probably is indicative that your code is not reachable or probably not being served via a HTTPS endpoint. I suggest the following:

- Is the code available over a publicly accessible endpoint?
- If the above is yes, is it being served over a secure channel i.e. HTTPS?

Comment: I have used this code inside the inline editor itself 
May be I need to create deploy this somewhere 
What do you think ??

Comment: Just a question : Assuming that this is Firebase functions, have you deployed the code?